# How to concatenate mxArray vector efficiently

Tags: c++, matlab

In MATLAB script, we can do

```
a = [1 2 3]
a = [a 4]
```

Does internally MATLAB reallocate/copy memory or use reserved memory until it is not big enough? I guess it may do the later to improve performance. It could optimize in this way because MATLAB knows no one refers to the original a after the append.

How can we concatenate mxArray in the same way? mlCreate needs explicit dimension sizes, and mlfVertcat seems returning a new one? I am not sure if mlfVectcat or mlfCat can work w/o reallocation.

We can do the following manually. Does there exist any similar utilities?

```
class mxDynamicDoubleVector {

public:
    mxDynamicDoubleVector(mwSize reservedSize = 2);

    void pushBack(double d);

    const mxArray *getData() const {
        return data_;
    }

    ~mxDynamicDoubleVector();

private:
    mxDynamicDoubleVector(const mxDynamicDoubleVector&);
    void operator = (const mxDynamicDoubleVector&);

    mwSize reservedSize_;    
    mxArray *data_;
};

mxDynamicDoubleVector::mxDynamicDoubleVector(mwSize reservedSize)
    : reservedSize_(reservedSize)
{
    data_ = mxCreateUninitNumericMatrix(1, reservedSize_, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
    mxSetN(data_, 0);
}

void mxDynamicDoubleVector::pushBack(double d) 
{   
    mwSize n = mxGetN(data_);
    if (n == reservedSize_) {
        double *ptr = mxGetPr(data_);
        reservedSize_ *= 2;
        ptr = static_cast<double*>(mxRealloc(ptr, sizeof(double) * reservedSize_));
        mxSetPr(data_, ptr);
    }
    double *ptr = mxGetPr(data_);
    ptr[n] = d;
    mxSetN(data_, n+1);
}

mxDynamicDoubleVector::~mxDynamicDoubleVector() 
{
    mxDestroyArray(data_);
}
```

Comment: MATLAB makes a complete copy in order to append in this manner. This is why pre-allocation is so important. Is there any reason that you cannot use pre-allocation in your mex code? The other option is to store a cell array inside of your mex function as this can be expanded with less overhead.

Comment: @Suever: With pre-allocation, we would mxCreate a large enough vector, mxSetDimensions to be 0, then resize dimensions when append, and mxReallocate the vector if it is not big enough. Does mxArray have any existing utilities to do the work? Do we use mlfCellhcat for the second option? I think it would also make a copy.

Comment: @Suever: I updated the question with a pre-allocation impl. Does it match what you proposed?